# How to restrict with predefined argument values while calling a keyword in robotframework

Tags: enums, robotframework

Using `robotframework`. Defined a `keyword` which has two input arguments as mentioned below:

1. searchFor - any string user would like to search for.
2. searchBy - here search can be done by based on this value like by `name, id, email` etc..

Here `searchBy` works only with pre-defined(valid) values like mentioned above.

**Question:** Is it possible to restrict the caller to use the keyword only with the valid values as argument value for  the `searchBy` parameter? And throw error otherwise with an error message, possibly, saying invalid values. (like `enum` in java)

Comment: It's an old question, I just wanted to mention that I bumped into the same issue. It's a shame that robot does not support anything enum-like, this would make so many things easier! Or did you find any more enum-like solutions OP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) to check if the variable has a supported value or not:

```
*** Keywords ***
| Find something
| | [Arguments] | ${searchFor} | ${searchBy}
| | run keyword if | '${searchBy}' not in ('name', 'id', 'email')
| | ... | Fail | searchBy '${searchBy}' is invalid: must be 'name', 'id' or 'email'
```

Comment: Thank you Bryan, does what I was looking for.